# Insert Null into database with Entity Framework sql

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, insert

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model.Item items = new Model.Item
    {
        Code = Convert.ToInt32(txtCode.Text),
        Name = txtName.Text,
        MQCode = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMinmumQuantityNo.Text) ? null :   txtMinmumQuantityNo.Text)
    };
    db.Items.Add(items);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Error

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Items_MQ". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\20101\DESKTOP\SIGMA V1\SIGMA V1\BIN\DEBUG\SIGMA.MDF", table "dbo.MQ", column 'MQCode'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You're not inserting `NULL`. `Convert.ToInt32` converts `null` to `0`. `0` isn't matching a record in the parent table.

Comment: Check the constraints on your foreign keys, some are not allowed to be null, some have to be unique. We cannot even see the type of MQCode here.

Comment: What can I use instead of   Convert.ToInt32  And gives the result = null ??

Comment: public Nullable<int> MQCode { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (linked below), Convert.ToInt32 returns 0 when the string parameter is *null*.

As such, the following line is setting MQCode to **0** which is an invalid Foreign Key value for MQCode.

```
MQCode = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMinmumQuantityNo.Text) ? null :   txtMinmumQuantityNo.Text)
```

Consider instead using the following:

```
MQCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMinmumQuantityNo.Text) ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(txtMinmumQuantityNo.Text)
```

This will either return a null or an integer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that field is not nullable. It must have an actual value.